# How to get client computer windows username in asp.net core web app

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to get window username from client computer in asp.net core web application.

I am not using Windows Authentication and have already tried
`System.Environment.UserName` & `Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name()`. These functions returns `AppPool Identity`

Comment: if you are not using windows authentication, what type of authentication are you using? it is giving you the App Pool Identity because it anonymous authentication by default which is the identity of the app pool

Comment: I am using an anonymous authentication. Trying to enable auto login for window-users if found in database. Web-app will run on intranet but we can not switch to windows auth.

Comment: i am confused. if you are using anonymous authentication, how can you enable auto login for windows users? your app is running with anonymous identity. it wouldn't know anything about the windows user identity for you to check if the user exist int he database.

Comment: Why can't you switch to windows authentication. What you call `auto login` doesn't exist and if it did, it would be a *colossal security hole* - everyone could impersonate everyone else by creating a local account with the name they wanted

Comment: Windows Authentication uses Kerberos. Even if you deploy to Linux you can [add the Linux server to the Windows domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#linux-and-macos-environment-configuration) and use Windows Authentication

Comment: @Baahubali We already have a system that need to be changed to enable this for specific users. We still validates if user exists in database and can auto login.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, We can't switch to Windows Auth as we still need standard Login function for few departments using this system.

Comment: Then you can't do auto login for Windows users, and you can't get their Windows username unless they're logged in via Windows auth, obviously. You'll either need to piggy back on an LDAP connection (attempting to authenticate via that before Identity during normal login with username and password (which is still going to be a manual process) or you can do an OAuth login flow via something like Azure AD, assuming your organization can use Azure AD, of coure.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, Thanks for response. Are you aware of any method that i can use to intercept the windows authentication and perform some functions specific to our system.

Comment: @Ajay you don't have to *switch*, you can use both

Comment: No. I covered that in my comment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You can't use both Windows Auth and Identity. They're incompatible. You can use Identity and supplement it with LDAP, to allow users to login via their Windows credentials, or you can use AD as an external authentication source like Google, Facebook, etc., but I think only the Azure version supports that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the easy but ugly way to do it is to use two endpoints just like we did in the Web Forms days. That's how SharePoint for example uses *both* Windows Auth and custom options.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, If we switch to Window Auth just to get the username, is it possible to hook some function once user is authenticated from windows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That won't work in Core, not sure what you might have done in Web Forms, but that wasn't even using Identity, but Membership, which was a totally different beast.

Comment: @Ajay if you switch to Windows Auth, you get an authenticated user, not just the name. You don't need to do anything else. I assume you want to support *both* Windows and another authentication method, eg forms or Google at the same time. If all you need is the Windows account, you don't need anything more